# volumes for quick dev on docker compose don't work

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, volumes

i create this docker-compose for my project (dev only) but for no particular reason on every OS the volume for ./back:/app and ./front:/app don't work (the other volumes work)

```
services:
  backend:
    build: ./back
    container_name: backend
    volumes:
      - ./back:/app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - back

  frontend:
    build: ./front
    container_name: frontend
    volumes:
      - ./front:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "8900:5173"
    depends_on:
      - backend

  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: gatekeeper
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3308:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - back

volumes:
  mysql_data:
networks:
  back:
```

detailled dockerfile for front and back
front :

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install -g vite

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

back:

```
FROM sapmachine:17

WORKDIR /app

COPY mvnw .

RUN chmod +x mvnw

COPY .mvn .mvn

COPY pom.xml .

RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline

COPY src ./src


EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run"]
```

actually the project build without any problem just the update of file from the computer to the docker don't work .

Comment: Since Java is a (semi-)compiled language, just bind-mounting source code into a Java container won't result in live-update behavior.  You need to rebuild the jar file and restart the application; and once you're doing that, removing the `volumes:` that hide the image contents and running `docker-compose up --build` isn't that big a deal.

Comment: You can also try `docker compose alpha watch` command to rebuild your image and restart your container automatically on every source file changes. See https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-compose-experiment-sync-files-and-automatically-rebuild-services-with-watch-mode/.